# PDFBox converting colorspace of existing pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, color-space

Problem:
I have a existing pdf which have some images and text. This pdf has mixed color space RGB and CMYK. I want to convert it into single color-space pdf preferably into CMYK.

Using : PDFBox 2.0.4

PDFBox has `PDPageContentStream` which can used to change the add color-space when adding data to the existing pdf like below:

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(myPdfWithMixColorSpace);
    PDPage pdPage = document.getPage(0);
    PDPageContentStream imageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    imageContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0, 255); // for cmyk color space

    imageContentStream.beginText();
    imageContentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 20.15f);
    imageContentStream.newLineAtOffset(13.55f, 50f);
    imageContentStream.showText("this is test");
    imageContentStream.endText();

    imageContentStream.close();  
    document.save("D:\\newPDF.pdf");
    document.close();
```

`newPDF.pdf` has the text added to it in CMYK color, But I don't want to add text or image in CMYK color on the existing pdf, but to convert the color-space of all the content of the input pdf itself.

In summary what I want  is:

Given a pdf having mix color space for image and text in it.

Then using pdfbox

Create a new pdf or update the existing pdf with cmyk color space for all its content.

Comment: Tricky. If it is just RGB, you could parse the content tokens as shown in the RemoveAllText.java example in the source code download. Then replace these with the appropriate CMYK operators and parameters. (see in the PDF specification "operator summary" and look for rg and RG, replace with k and K. (There are other ways to get RGB colors too) Where is gets more difficult is the images. You would have to convert the image to CMYK and then replace the stream and its attributes... this is certainly not done in a day.

Comment: Indeed, too broad for the stack overflow question and answer format.